# what is this - ERROR: Error 3050001: account name already exists?

Tags: nodeos, single-node

I am using python3 following a tutorial here - http://eosfactory.io/sphinx/build/html/tutorials/02.InteractingWithEOSContractsInEOSFactory.html#initialize-workspace

I am using Apple and this is a local installation.

I get the folllowing error - has anyone any idea the cause of this?

> > > > sess.init()
> > > >
> > > > ###  Create a `Wallet` object with the NODEOS wallet plugin. Pasword is restored from the file:
>
> /Users/satoshimaca/Projects/EOS/eosfactory/build/daemon/data-dir/wallet/passwords.json
>   Wallet directory is
>   /Users/satoshimaca/Projects/EOS/eosfactory/build/daemon/data-dir/wallet/
>   Opened wallet `default`.
>
> ###  Get master account. Local testnet is ON: the `eosio` account is master. ERROR: 3464009ms thread-0   main.cpp:2756
>
> main                 ] Failed with error: Assert Exception (10)
>
> ERROR: Error 3050001: account name already exists
>
> ERROR: Error 3050001: account name already exists
>
> ERROR: Error 3050001: account name already exists
>
> ERROR: Reading WAST/WASM from
>   /Users/satoshimaca/Projects/EOS/eos/build/contracts/eosio.bios/eosio.bios.wast...
>   Assembling WASM... Publishing contract... 3464467ms thread-0
>   main.cpp:2756                 main                 ] Failed with
>   error: Assert Exception (10)
>
> ## Available test accounts: eosio, alice, carol, bob

Comment: What command gives you this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sess.init() creates several test accounts. If you run that method more than once then it is not possible to create these accounts again. That is an exception is thrown with `account name already exists`.